# Since the Q-criterion is a scalar, does it not change upon moving reference frames?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, tensor-calculus

Based on the definition from [An objective definition of a vortex](http://georgehaller.com/reprints/vortex.pdf), the $Q$-criterion is $$Q=\frac{1}{2}(|\boldsymbol{\Omega}|^2-|\mathbf{S}|^2)$$ where $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is the rotation rate tensor, and $\mathbf{S}$ is the strain rate tensor. I'm pretty sure that since both of the above are tensors that depend on the velocity gradient $\nabla \vec{v}$, they would change upon moving to a new reference frame. But $Q$ is a scalar that depends on their magnitudes, so I think that should remain unchanged. Am I correct in my understanding that the latter $Q$ should be independent of the changes of reference frame?